# NullPointerException AsyncTask android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I have a problem with `AsyncTask` in android. I have a `NullPointerException` at this line

```
  ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)  
  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

in this method

```
public static boolean checkRete(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo infos[] = conMgr.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo info : infos) {
        if (info.getState() == State.CONNECTED)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This error causes a Runtime Exception while executing `doInBackground()` part of `AsyncTask` class.

```
protected ArrayList<ObjDb> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return Functions.query(act, "http://www.unishare.it/tutored/" + url);
}
```

This is the entire log of error:

```
04-06 18:06:40.082  25316-25365/it.polimi.mobilecourse.expenses E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at it.polimi.mobilecourse.expenses.Functions.checkRete(Functions.java:36)
            at it.polimi.mobilecourse.expenses.Functions.query(Functions.java:27)
            at it.polimi.mobilecourse.expenses.RequestFtp.doInBackground(RequestFtp.java:33)
            at it.polimi.mobilecourse.expenses.RequestFtp.doInBackground(RequestFtp.java:14)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

and these are other methods. The method `checkRete()` is called by:

```
 static ArrayList<ObjDb> query(Context context, String url) {
    System.out.println(url);
    if(!checkRete(context)) {
        System.out.println("Problema rete");
        return null;
    }
```

that is called by `doInBackground()`. I have already set the permission in Manifest for WiFi and 3g connection. Why I found this error? Please,help me!

Edit:
context comes from this:

```
         new RequestFtp().setParameters(activity, url, "controlloFB", LandingFragment.this).execute();
```

where setParameters sets context to activity that is a simple Activity.

Edit 2:

```
   public class RequestFtp extends AsyncTask<Void,ArrayList<ObjDb>,ArrayList<ObjDb>> {

private String url;
private Fragment fragment;
private String op;
private HelpActivity act;

public RequestFtp setParameters(HelpActivity activity, String url,String op, Fragment fragment) {
    this.url = url;
    this.op=op;
    this.act=activity;
    this.fragment = fragment;
    return this;
}


/** The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and
 * delivers it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute() */
protected ArrayList<ObjDb> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return Functions.query(act, "http://www.unishare.it/tutored/" + url);
}
/** The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and delivers
 * the result from doInBackground() */
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ObjDb> result) {
    if(result == null) {
        Toast.makeText(act.getApplicationContext(),R.string.error_connection,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    act.handleResult(result,op,fragment);

}
```

}

Fragment:

```
        public class LandingFragment extends Fragment {

private View view;
private LandingActivity activity;
private String str;


int id;
String nome;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.landing_fragment, container, false);
    buttonsActions();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);


    this.activity = (LandingActivity) activity;
}

public void buttonsActions() {

    Button butS = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonStudente);
    butS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myintent = new Intent(v.getContext(), LoginStudente.class);
            startActivity(myintent);

        }
    });

    Button butT = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonTutor);
    butT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myintent = new Intent(v.getContext(), LoginTutor.class);
            startActivity(myintent);

        }
    });


}

private void buttonsSActions() {

    Button butS = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonStudente);
    butS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myintent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DataActivityStudent.class);
            Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
            mBundle.putString("Nome", nome);
            mBundle.putInt("Id", id);
            myintent.putExtras(mBundle);
            startActivity(myintent);

        }
    });

    Button butT = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonTutor);
    butT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myintent = new Intent(v.getContext(), LoginTutor.class);
            startActivity(myintent);

        }
    });
    try {
        ((manageListener) activity).manageButton();
    }
    catch(ClassCastException cce){

    }


}

private void buttonsTActions() {

    Button butS = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonStudente);
    butS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myintent = new Intent(v.getContext(), LoginStudente.class);
            startActivity(myintent);

        }
    });

    Button butT = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonTutor);
    butT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myintent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DataActivityTutor.class);
            startActivity(myintent);

        }
    });
    try {
        ((manageListener) activity).manageButton();
    }
    catch(ClassCastException cce){

    }


}


public void ftpControl(String url) {

    new RequestFtp().setParameters(activity, url, "controlloFB", LandingFragment.this).execute();
}


private void setNomeWelcome(String nome) {
    WelcomeFragment wf = activity.getWf();
    wf.setText(nome);
}


public void control(ArrayList<ObjDb> result) {

    ObjDb res = result.get(0);
    String response = res.get("Response");
    //System.out.println("Response "+response);
    if (response.compareTo("S") == 0) {

        str = "S";
        String id_utente = res.get("id_utente");
        nome = res.get("nome");
        //System.out.println("nome "+nome);
        id = Integer.parseInt(id_utente);
        buttonsSActions();


    }
    if (response.compareTo("T") == 0) {

        str = "T";
        String id_utente = res.get("id_utente");
        nome = res.get("nome");
        id = Integer.parseInt(id_utente);
        buttonsTActions();


    }
    if (nome.compareTo("") != 0) {
        setNomeWelcome(nome);
    }


}


public interface manageListener{

    public void manageButton();
}
```

}

Activity:

```
       public class LandingActivity extends HelpActivity implements LandingFragment.manageListener {


private LandingFragment lf;
private WelcomeFragment wf;
private ProgressBar progressView;


private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Session.StatusCallback callback;

String nome;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setLanding();
    progress(true);
    showWelcome();
    manageSession(savedInstanceState);




}

private void manageSession(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    callback=new Session.StatusCallback(){
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session,final SessionState state,final Exception exception){



            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);






        }
    };
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this,callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
    Session session=Session.getActiveSession();
    if(session.getPermissions().isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("logged false");

        FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragTrans=fragMan.beginTransaction();
        fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragreplace,lf).commit();
        progress(false);

    }


}

private void setLanding(){
    setContentView(R.layout.landing_activity);

    progressView=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBarRS);
    lf=new LandingFragment();

    wf=new WelcomeFragment();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}

@Override
public void handleResult(ArrayList<ObjDb> result,String op,Fragment fragment){


    if(result==null){
        progress(false);
    }

    if(op=="controlloFB"){
        LandingFragment lfr=(LandingFragment) fragment;
        lfr.control(result);
    }


}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {



    if(session==null || session.isClosed()){
        Log.i("LandingActivity", "session nulla...");



    }


    if(session!=null && session.isOpened()){

        Log.i("LandingActivity", "session not null...");



        System.out.println(session.getPermissions());

        new Request(session,"me",null, HttpMethod.GET,new Request.Callback(){
            public void onCompleted(Response response){
                String us=null;
                try {
                us=response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email").toString();
                nome=response.getGraphObject().getProperty("first_name").toString();

                }
                catch(NullPointerException e){
                     System.out.println(response.getError());
                }
                String url="exist_user.php?mail=".concat(us);
                lf.ftpControl(url);
            }

        }).executeAsync();

    }


}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
            (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}



public void showWelcome(){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.welcomemessage, wf);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


}

public WelcomeFragment getWf(){

    return wf;
}




public void progress(final boolean show){
    final int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime);

    progressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    progressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            progressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    });



}

private void showButton(){
    System.out.println("logged true");
    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragreplace,lf).commit();
}




public void manageButton(){
    progress(false);
    showButton();

}
```

}

Log:

```
       04-07 16:17:11.418  24319-24319/it.polimi.mobilecourse.expenses E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at it.polimi.mobilecourse.expenses.RequestFtp.onPostExecute(RequestFtp.java:42)
        at it.polimi.mobilecourse.expenses.RequestFtp.onPostExecute(RequestFtp.java:14)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: how are you passing your context object?

Comment: what is checkRete(Functions.java:36) line 36 of Functions.java?

Comment: I'd have to assume that the context passed in was null.

Comment: @inner_class7 checkRete is a method. I have copied that on top.

Comment: Please post the async task code as well as the file you are using to call your asynctask

Comment: @inner_class7 I added the classes.

Comment: See under UPDATE below your not using onAttach correctly so you can remove this

Comment: See updated Answer where i suggest calling getActivity() to get context...

Comment: @inner_class7 I had to cast getActivity() with HelpActivity to do your suggestion. But,anyway, it produces again the same error. Can I have your contact? So,you can help me directly.

Comment: @inner_class7 Can I have your contact? So,you can help me directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `Context` object. It's null.

In android the context is very important to know which page is being considered to refresh with the corresponding changes.

When you call this method:

```
checkRete(Context context)
```

make sure that context is not null.

Comment: Your advice not correct the problem. It avoids the crash only.

Comment: And what happens next; does it generate another error?

Comment: Now,I have the error that I have posted on top. A NullPointerException in RequestFtp class

Comment: have you got any idea?

Comment: Good question. I don't understand why.

Comment: what value do you pass to it?

Comment: what? I've written all under the @inner_class7 post.

Comment: You are not helping me,bye.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to GingerHead's answer

First make sure your using the right context.

Create class member:

```
 Context mContext;
```

Initialize in onCreate of Activity:

```
  mContext = this;
```

Or if it's from a fragment in onActivityCreated call:

```
  mContext = getActivity();
```

Then use your mContext:

```
   Functions.query(mContext, "www.myurl.com");
```

Additionally make sure it's not null in your method before passing it to checkRete:

```
 static ArrayList<ObjDb> query(Context context, String url) {
    System.out.println(url);
    // check context before using it
    if(context != null){
        if(!checkRete(context)) {
            System.out.println("Problema rete");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You are using onAttach(Activity activity) incorrectly, this is designed to attach interface callbacks that should be implemented in the parent for Fragment to Activity communication:

REMOVE this:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.activity = (LandingActivity) activity;
}
```

then in:

```
 public void ftpControl(String url) {

    // Call getActivity() here
    new RequestFtp().setParameters(getActivity(), url, "controlloFB", LandingFragment.this).execute();
 }
```

Comment: I'll try this piece of code. Thanks for the moment.

Comment: @hteo how are you referring to context? this code will only help you not to make your app crash... you need good context for this to work

Comment: setParameters() is used in a Fragment. the variable activity that I use in setParameters() is an Activity variable that I passed by onAttach() method of that fragment. Why the context(activity variable) is null?

Comment: Sorry,but now I have a NullPointerException at this line:         act.handleResult(result,op,fragment);
where handleResult is a method of Activity. I post the Activity on the top.

Comment: inner,you are very patient but your update doesn't work. I haeve the same error. I put the log on top.

Comment: in RequestFtp class,act is a private attribute that is written by setParameters().

Comment: @hteo yeah but i do not see it as a member of your AsyncTask and it looks like your are passing LandingActivity context but then calling a method in HelpActivity that is what is causing your null pointer

Comment: ok,but I don't call any method of HelpActivity and LandingActivity extends HelpActivity. I don't understand what can I do with this exception..

Comment: in any case,RequestFtp class works correctly with other classes. I don't think that the problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in line number 36 for your function class , you are using any object which is not initialized. OR else put some more code

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at it.polimi.mobilecourse.expenses.Functions.checkRete(Functions.java:36)
            at it.polimi.mobilecourse.expenses.Functions.query(Functions.java:27)
```