# facebook android call activity

Tags: java, android, facebook, fragment

I have a problem with my application. I have a fragment in my activity that call the facebook login session. When the login is finished,the application returns to the activity. I want that,when the user is correctly logged,it is redirected to another activity. Now I paste here the code:
This is the fragment contained in the activity:

```
public class FBSFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {


private boolean logged;
private Activity ctx;
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private View view;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loginfb, container, false);
    ctx=getActivity();
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setOnErrorListener(new LoginButton.OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.e("FBSFragment", "Error " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile","email"));

    authButton.setFragment(this.getTargetFragment());




    return view;

}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    final Intent myintent = new Intent(getActivity(), DataActivityStudent.class);
    final Intent closint=new Intent(this.getActivity(),LandingActivity.class);

    System.out.println(session.getPermissions());


    if (session.isOpened()) {
        Log.i("FBSFragment", "Logged in...");

        new Request(session,"me",null, HttpMethod.GET,new Request.Callback(){
            public void onCompleted(Response response){

                String email=null;
                String nome=null;
                try {
                    email=response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email").toString();
                    nome=response.getGraphObject().getProperty("first_name").toString();

                }
                catch(NullPointerException e){
                    System.out.println(response.getError());
                }
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("Mail",email);
                bundle.putString("Nome",nome);
                Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), RegistrationStudent.class);
                startActivity(myintent);

            }

        }).executeAsync();


    } else if (session.isClosed()) {
        Log.i("FBSFragment", "Logged out...");

    }



}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
            (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

}

With this code,when the user is logged,it returns at the activity LoginActivity (that contain FBSFragment) for one second and it is redirect to RegistrationStudent activity. I want that the application go immediately to RegistrationStudent activity,without passing for the activity that contain FBSFragment. Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the redirect to a new activity to happen right away you will need to move the Intent outside of the Request callback because the Intent won't fire until the callback is called.

It doesn't seem like you are passing the data from the request in the Intent as an Extra so why not make the Request to "me" in the RegistrationStudent activity.

Comment: So,your advice is to move the Intent outside (after the executeAsync())?and move all the "me" request in the activity?

Comment: Well it depends on what you are looking to do. If you need the data in the FBSFragment then you need to keep it as you have it. If you don't then yes, move the Intent to after the executeAsync(). The reason why it takes a couple of seconds to load is because it must wait till the Async request is finished before the callback is triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the moment. I'll try and I'll let you know

Comment: Can you help me also about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475308/nullpointerexception-asynctask-android/29475462?noredirect=1#comment47249857_29475462